# Dynamically create model validations and attributes in Rails without a database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, metaprogramming

I am new to Rails and I am trying to use some metaprogramming in order to automate a few things. What I am trying to do is essentially generate a database-less Rails model. The reason for this is so I can generate models, validations, forms, etc. based on some metadata in a file.

The problem now is that I probably have some errors in the way I try to do the metaprogramming.

This (**simplistic example**) works:

```
class User
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  validates_presence_of :forename, :surname

  def initialize(attrs = {})
    self.class.class_eval { attr_accessor :forename, :surname }

    send("forename=", attrs['forename'])
    send("surname=", attrs['surname'])
  end
end
```

But this doesn't:

```
class User
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  def initialize(attrs = {})
    self.class.class_eval { attr_accessor :forename, :surname }

    # moved the validation line in here
    self.class.class_eval { validates_presence_of :forename, :surname }

    send("forename=", attrs['forename'])
    send("surname=", attrs['surname'])
  end
end
```

The way I realized it doesn't work is because I have a form for this model. When I hit submit multiple times with empty fields, I see error messages from before (ie. the errror messages accumulate over different requests).

I must be doing something really wrong in the code so was wondering if someone more experienced could guide me towards the right direction.

Comment: Replacing `self.class.class_eval` with simply `class_eval` seems to fix it but no idea why..

Comment: Here's why: `class_eval` evaluates block of code in the context of class of current `self`. Now, what would be the class of `self.class`?